# Android Manifest: Some devices are not supported?

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest, google-play

I have an app on Android Market that should run on everything >= Android 1.5. When testing this indeed seems to work, but I get reports from frustrated would be users that they are not allowed to install it due to compatibility issues. Two such are HTC Hero running Android 2.1 and HTC Wildfire (version unknown).

My entire manifest is below (As I don't know what's wrong, I might remove something important) - as I see it, this is the only thing Android Market looks to for compatibility information. Am I somehow excluding certain devices?

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".ShowStreams" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".menu.Settings" />
    <activity android:name=".ClearCache"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".settings.ManageFeeds"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".settings.DirectoryBrowser"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".settings.SourceSelector"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".settings.FlickrBrowser"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".settings.PicasaBrowser"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".parser.facebook.FacebookAuth">
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
             <data android:scheme="floatingimage"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".settings.FacebookBrowser">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".parser.facebook.WebAuth"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".parser.facebook.FacebookAlbumBrowser"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".parser.facebook.FacebookFriendsBrowser"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".parser.facebook.FacebookFriendView"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".flickr.WebAuth"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".parser.flickr.FlickrAlbumBrowser"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".parser.picasa.PicasaWebAuth"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".parser.picasa.PicasaAlbumBrowser"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".parser.picasa.PicasaUserView"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".settings.About" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".menu.WallpaperSettings" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name=".menu.ApplicationFeedManagerLauncher"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".menu.WallpaperFeedManagerLauncher"></activity>

    <service android:name="Wallpaper"
             android:label="Floating Image"
             android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
             </intent-filter>
             <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper" android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />
    </service>
</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />

<supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, and also asking at #android-dev I found that the problem was with the line:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />
```

This is apparently a hard requirement for the app, and not necessary for live wallpaper functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "hard requirement"? I am having the same issue. I had `<uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" require="true"/>` and my testers could not install. I changed it to "false" and now they can install but it crashes.

Comment: It means that the app requires this feature to be present for it to function at all. If it is not present, Android blocks the install. Now if your app also does other things, and live wallpaper is only a secondary feature, you don't want to use this tag. Not sure why it would fail on newer droids though...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the limiting factor might be the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission>
```

According to the following page in the android docs, this was introduced in api level 8.  Is it possible that the unsupported permission is being filtered out for devices running sdk at api level 7?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BIND_WALLPAPER